# FFMPEG Overlay Not Found For Putting Watermark in Video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to put a logo in an rtmp stream using ffmpeg. My version of ffmpeg is `ffmpeg version 4.3.1` Currently in my complex filter I have:

```
ffmpeg  -re -i 'video.mp4' -filter_complex "tpad=start_duration=10:stop_duration=15:start_mode=add:color=black:stop_mode=add"  -f flv rtmp://example.com/a/stream
```

And it works! But when I add :overlay=0:0 at the end:

```
ffmpeg  -re -i 'video.mp4'  -i image.jpeg -filter_complex "tpad=start_duration=10:stop_duration=15:start_mode=add:color=black:stop_mode=add:overlay=0:0"  -f flv rtmp://example.com/a/stream
```

I get the errors:

```
[Parsed_tpad_0 @ 0x555bc5d99f40] Option 'overlay' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x555bc5e7a980] Error initializing filter 'tpad' with args 'start_duration=10:stop_duration=15:start_mode=add:color=black:stop_mode=add:overlay=0:0'
Error initializing complex filters.
Option not found
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -re -i 'video.mp4' -i image.jpeg -filter_complex "tpad=start_duration=10:stop_duration=15:start_mode=add:color=black:stop_mode=add[bg];[bg][1]overlay" -f flv rtmp://example.com/a/stream
```

- The [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) filter requires 2 inputs but you are only giving it 1.
- Filters in the same linear chain are separated by commas (`,`) and distinct linear chains of filters are separated by semicolons (`;`). See [FFmpeg Filtering Introduction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction).